# How to show a confirmation box on CheckboxList selectedIndexChange?

Tags: javascript, c#, checkboxlist, confirm

I have a CheckBoxList and I want to add a confirmation box ONLY on a second ListItem (LOCKED). I mean, If selected item is "LOCKED", show confirmation box, in the other case don't".

Here is myCheckBoxList

```
  <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" ID="cblFlags" onselectedindexchanged="cblFlags_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="VALID"  Value="ISVALID"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="LOCKED" Value="ISLOCKED"></asp:ListItem>
 </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

and this is my code behind

```
protected void cblFlags_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItems = cblFlags.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected);

    foreach (ListItem selectedItem in selectedItems)
    {
          if(selectedItem.Value == "ISLOCKED")
              cblFlags.Attributes.Add("onclick", "if (!confirm('Are you sure ?')) return false;");
    }
}
```

The problem is that Confirmation box shows everytime- when I check and uncheck  any checkboxList Item.

Does anyone has an Idea how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Bind the `onclick` event on ListItem `selectedItem` instead of `cblFlags` which is CheckBoxList

```
foreach (ListItem selectedItem in cblFlags.Items)
{
      if(selectedItem.Value == "ISLOCKED")
          selectedItem.Attributes.Add("onclick", "if (!confirm('Are you sure ?')) return false;");
}
```

**Edit**

I think you need to change the loop by using `cblFlags.Items` instead of `selectedItems`, as you are binding javascript event only to selected elements **once you un select the checkbox and after that in the postback the event wont bind again as execution wont go in `foreach` loop**. Check my updated code its working for me as far as my understanding is concerned.

Comment: Thank you, but It works only If I UNCHECK the "ISLOCKED" item. When I CHECK the item it doesn't works

Comment: Do you have any client side code that might be changing IsLocked property?

Comment: You probably have to move it from cblFlags_SelectedIndexChanged to page_load

Comment: Keep in mind you are binding the click event to only selected checkboxes, also tell me if you have postback on checkbox selection?

Comment: I have a AutoPostBack="True" on a CheckBoxList

Comment: Can you test it by setting AutoPostBack="False"

Comment: When I set AutoPostBack="False" nothing happens when I check/uncheck the Items

Comment: Well, I placed on Page_Load  this 

 ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(cblFlags);

and that row  fixed the problem

Comment: Yes, but No :D...This is not a fix from the problem :)

Comment: I think you need to change the loop by using cblFlags.Items instead of selectedItems, as you are binding javascript event only to selected elements once you unchange in the postback the event wont bind again. Check my updated code its working for me as far as my understanding is concerned